# passing multiple parameters to a shell script from Automator

Tags: bash, shell, automator

forgive a newbie question.I have searched high and low but not found a similar situation.

I'm trying to create an automatic process where I can add keywords to jpg images.

I'm using Hazel to monitor a folder on my Mac and when it finds a file, it calls an Automator workflow script. Thus the script already receives one parameter (filename and path)

The shell script executes the following (using pass input: as arguments)  (shell: /bin/bash)

```
for f in "$@"
do
    exiftool -keywords=myKeyWord "$1"
    exiftool -delete_original! "$1"
done
```

So far everything works. What I can't figure out is how to pass a second parameter from Automator that will allow me to input a keyword from a dialog box.

I have tried to a text field (Action: Ask for Text), and update the hardcoded value 'myKeyWord' with "$2", but it gives me an error stating "1 files weren't updated due to errors"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

The loop is iterated for every parameter to the script. However, within the loop only the first parameter is being used: `$1` instead of `$f` . So if you call the script with say 3 parameters it does the following:

```
exiftool -keywords=myKeyWord "$1"
exiftool -delete_original! "$1"
exiftool -keywords=myKeyWord "$1"
exiftool -delete_original! "$1"
exiftool -keywords=myKeyWord "$1"
exiftool -delete_original! "$1"
```

---

Perhaps you mean to do something like this (without a loop)? Just guessing :

```
exiftool -keywords="$2" "$1"
exiftool -delete_original! "$1"
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do. I removed the loop statement but it still doesn't work. The statement is now only:                 do
    exiftool -keywords="$2" "$1"
 exiftool -delete_original! "$1"
 
done Am I missing something?

Comment: @user3595091 Remove `do` and `done`, they should not be there . Also try to execute with `set -x` to see what is happening if it still does not work. I do not know what the command needs, you would need to check the man page..